# How to "configure" javascript on client's side by remote json?

Tags: javascript, json

I have my library injected in the client's website and i want to be able to configure it by feeding it a remote json (based on client's ID). What is the best way to do that? Simply using ajax is not really desirable because of CORS as we have to support older browsers (especially IE), where this can be an issue. 
Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need to support IE7? It's been unsupported by Microsoft for forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

1. add configure function on your library
2. add endpoint on your server which will render `configure({<....your
   json config object....>});`
3. add calling your backend as
4. don't forget about proper server response headers